# Can I specify GitHub Actions runs-on as either one label or another (OR logic instead of AND logic)

Tags: github-actions

I would like, if possible, to configure my GitHub Actions workflow so it runs on **either one label or another**.

For example, I may want to specify that a job can run either on `ubuntu-latest`, the GitHub-provided runner, or on `my-ubuntu-latest`, a self-hosted runner I provide.

I have a queue mechanism on my own ephemeral, self-hosted runner with a slight queue delay, and it is set so that it won't start a runner if the job is no longer pending.  So my idea is to specify two labels.  If I have [sufficient capacity in my org](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/usage-limits-billing-and-administration#usage-limits) to immediately run on the GitHub-provided runners it should start there; then when my self-hosted runner goes to start, it will see it is no longer pending and won't start my self-hosted ephemeral runner at all.  In this way, I can use my GitHub-provided capacity to the max first, then fall back to my self-hosted capacity if I am throttled or delayed in some way such that the GitHub-provided runners don't immediately pick up my job.

Can this sort of "either/or" logic be implemented for the `runs-on`?

[Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idruns-on) specifies

> If you specify an array of strings or variables, your workflow will
> execute on any runner that matches all of the specified runs-on
> values. For example, here the job will only run on a self-hosted
> runner that has the labels linux, x64, and gpu:

> ```
> runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, x64, gpu]
> ```

So that says the logic is "and" logic instead of "or" logic if there are multiple labels, but I am wondering if someone has found a way to make it "or" logic.

Comment: If I understand it clearly - your self-hosted agent has `wait-and-see-if-github-will-take-it` logic? `use-selfhosted-only-if-pending-on-timeout`?


If so... wouldn't adding `ubuntu-latest` label to your self-host and changing to `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` work?

Comment: @ravenwing Yes, I suppose that would do it.  I hadn't thought of it that way.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: let us know whether it worked. :)
 For the sake of future generations